Overflow Styling Lost When Scrolling
I have a standard table which consists of a header row and n-data rows.  The width of the table exceeds the size of the container in which it resides.  I have styling on the header row (white background) which seems to truncate at the end of the viewable table.  The overflow portion of the table does not seem to have the style applied.  Is there something I am missing?
CSS
.grid-wrapper {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    text-align: center;

    > .gt-header {
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: white;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }

    #training {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: $grid-psta-training
    }
    #training-data > div {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: $grid-psta-training;
        text-align: center;
    }
}

I used min-width: 100% with the hope that the styling would apply to the overflow area but with not luck.  The area is left un-styled.
Codepen Example: https://codepen.io/dmytrie/pen/jOjGeXE
If you scroll you'll notice the light green background-color is truncated which is undesirable.
Update 2:
After playing around with it further it seems that the issue stems from the grid-template-column sizes.  If the number of columns and its widths exceed the size of the viewport then the styling is truncated if and only if the last template-column value is a non-fractional unit.  Is there any properties we can use to ignore that. I'm open to using definite pixel sizes but that is really undesirable.

Can you provide a minimal reproducible example which includes HTML too so contributors can help you with your problem?

I apologize for not including the minimal reproducible example.

Initially, it appears there may be a structural issue with your HTML.
.grid-wrapper {
overflow-x: auto;
text-align: center;
white-space: nowrap;

>.gt-header {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#training {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: var(--grid-psta-training);
    width: max-content;
}} #training-data > div {

display: grid;
grid-template-columns: var(--grid-psta-training);
text-align: center;}


Any thoughts on why it might be acting like it is?  I tried using your code but it continues to truncate the styling at the edge of the view when overflowing.  Not sure why.

At first, use <table>.

What benefits does a table provide that a div setup cannot?  I understand that a table is preferable.

Look If you want to show something which is look like a table use <table> because that give us a default structure. If you use <div> for the table structure you need to do lots of work on it. So I suggest.

<table class="grid-wrapper">
    <thead >
      <tr id="training" class="gt-header">
        <th></th>
        <th>Course</th>
        <th>Registered Date</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>End Date</th>
        <th>Completed</th>
        <th>Comments</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="background-color: lightgreen;">
      <tr id="training-data" >
        <td>
          <i>{{ F.A.Icon }}</i>
        </td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>9/25/2011</td>
        <td>10/1/2011</td>
        <td>11/15/2011</td>
        <td>No</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

.grid-wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-style: all;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid-wrapper>.gt-header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25px minmax(0, 0.75fr) minmax(0, 0.75fr) minmax(0, 0.75fr) minmax(0, 0.75fr) minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 20px);
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.grid-wrapper #training {
  grid-template-columns: 25px minmax(0, 0.75fr) minmax(0, 0.75fr) minmax(0, 0.75fr) minmax(0, 0.75fr) minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 20px);
  overflow-style: all;
}

.grid-wrapper #training-data {
  width: 100%;
}

.grid-wrapper #training-data>td {
  background-color: red;
}

